# Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, base64

I am trying to get base64 string from image file. When I am using following method

```
Future convertBase64(file) async{
    List<int> imageBytes = fileImage.readAsBytesSync();
    String base64Image = await 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64Encode(imageBytes);
//    print('length of image bytes ${base64Image.length}');
    return base64Image;
  }
```

It shows me an error :

```
exception---- Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

If I use without future it directly pass to next step without converting to base64 String. It usually takes time to convert.

Comment: The error does not seem to come from the code you posted. Perhaps from code that calls `convertBase64(file)`.

Comment: Consider using `Uri.dataFromBytes(imageBytes, mimeType: "image/png")` to do the encoding to URI, instead of building it yourself.

Comment: I agree with @GünterZöchbauer, it seems that you need to [show your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) calling the method `convertBase64(file)` so we will have a view of what's happening in your app.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `fileImage` doesn't seem to match the variable `file` passed to the function. Might this be the one causing the issue?

I'm curious on why the need to call `await` on a `String` - this seems to be unnecessary. The error might be caused on how `convertBase64()` was called. For async methods like `Future<T>`, I suggest calling it like:

```dart
convertBase64(imageFile).then((String base64Image) {
  // Handle base64Image 
});
```

Also, as previously recommended in the comments, it's better to use `Uri.dataFromBytes()` instead of parsing the encoded String on your own.

```
Future<String> convertBase64(File file) async{
  List<int> imageBytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
  return Uri.dataFromBytes(imageBytes, mimeType: "image/png").toString();
}
```